# How to ssh inside a local netwrok using an external IP?

Tags: ssh, ip

I can only ssh locally. I tried to ssh from my laptop in an external network but I wasn't able to do that. So I went home and did some troubleshooting. Now I want to ssh from my local network to that server externally(using a remote address or an external IP address). So is there a method I can use to do that ?

Comment: contact your network administrator. they will have to allow your traffic inbound in order for you to connect.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you. I had a strong feeling that they were behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options here:

- Your network administrator blocks inside SSH access

  - Ask them to fix it.
- Your server doesn't port forward

  - Forward the port on your router
  - Make an [reverse ssh tunnel](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) (if you have a port forwarded server)

I hope that solves it for you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into your router settings and do [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) to your server's IP and 22 port.

Hope this solution will help.